# Facebook graph API does not provide all taps list

Tags: facebook, api, graph

Facebook graph API provides only 3 tabs.
1 Photos
2 Likes
3 Videos

Graph API does not provide other taps ex : Timeline,Others..

API Call : GET /v2.5/{page-id}/tabs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your question is, but i´ll try to answer anyway:

- "Timeline" is not really an installable tab, so it makes sense that it does not show up. You can always be sure that there is a Timeline, so you don´t really need to get the information.
- The rest depends on the installed tabs, i get "Photos", "Likes" and "Events" for one of my Pages as i don´t have a Video tab but one for events.
- Custom Tabs (Page Apps) should always show up. If they don´t, you should file a bug.